# How to fix table rows while scrolling ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using ant design table in my React js project. It has column fix option with scroll props. I need to fix first 2 rows with header. Is it possible to do this in ant design or other frameworks.
For example in below. When scrolling `Edward King 0`  and  `Edward King 1`  have to be fixed others scroll in y-axis

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJw7O.png)

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can add your first two rows to the header and style these child header rows like the default rows.

Here is a [working example](https://codepen.io/cesarnml/pen/ExVMooE) at Codepen.

Example code:

````
const {  Table  } = antd;

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name1',
        children: [
      {
        title: 'Summary',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name2',
      },
    ],
    sorter: (a, b) => a.name - b.name
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    children: [
      {
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
      },
    ],
     sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age

  },
  {
    title: 'Company',
    children: [
      {
        dataIndex: 'companyAddress',
        key: 'companyAddress',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Gender',
    dataIndex: 'gender',
    key: 'gender',
     children: [
      {
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: i + 1,
    street: 'Lake Park',
    building: 'C',
    number: 2035,
    companyAddress: 'Lake Street 42',
    companyName: 'SoftLake Co',
    gender: 'M',
  });
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    bordered
    size="middle"
    scroll={{ x: 'calc(700px + 50%)', y: 240 }}
  />,
  mountNode,
);```


  [1]: https://codepen.io/cesarnml/pen/ExVMooE
````

Comment: What if rows have editable text box or select. How can I achieve it in header ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it using the ediatble header option in the antd dropdown

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).